# In bash updating file every hour if the last line is changed

Tags: bash, date, scripting, sed, awk

I have a data file which I parse for date and value every once every hour. So today I would have date=30 AUG 2012 and value=10. Then I want to append new file with this date and value only if the date or value is changed. So I am guessing i would need to check the last line of the new file and if it's different, append. Please help me devise the script to do that. I dont have cron available so I will run it in infinite loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tail -1 gives you the last line of a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# infinite loop
while true
do
my_file=test.txt
# get your date and value from where ever
my_date="30 AUG 2012"
my_value=10

lastval=`tail -1 $my_file | awk -F: '{print $1}'`
if [ "$lastval" != "$my_date" ] ; then
  echo "$my_date:$my_value" >> $my_file
fi

# if the file is updated every hour, check more often than once per hour.
sleep 30m

done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
current="$(tail -n 1 $DATA_FILE)"         # Last line of data file
previous="$(tail -n 1 $OTHER_FILE)"       # Last line of log file
if [ "$current" != "$previous" ]; then    # If the last lines are different...
  echo "$current" >> $OTHER_FILE          # ... append the current data
fi
```

Comment: Probably ought to also update `previous="$current"` inside that `if [...]` block...

Comment: Why?  The variables will update each time the snippet executes.